# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected 'end of template' - how to pass array values run time to a variable in dag

Tags: python, airflow

we are trying to pass array ['/home/arya/'] under params as below and while passing the arrays we are facing **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected 'end of template'**

and for integers as well we are facing issue.

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="INSURANCE_CALC",
    start_date= datetime(2022, 1, 24),
    schedule_interval=None,
    default_args=default_args,
    params= {
        "param2": "arya2@gmail.com",
        "sourcedir": ['/home/arya/'],
        "timenum": 0
    },
    catchup=False
) as dag


for number in range(0,len('{{ params.sourcedir}}'))):
    srcdir.append(("abc" + '{{ params.sourcedir}}'[number] + "xyz"))
    taskinfo = Operator(   task_id="taskinfo",  sourcedir=srcdir[task_no] )
```

reading above params as **'{{ params.sourcedir}}'** and passing them as a variable to the tasks.

An suggestion how to handle this ?

Comment: can you please share the code you are using the params?

Answer (score 1):

1. range should get an integer number not a list.
2. by default each param type is string. if you want to get it as its native type, you should add `render_template_as_native_obj=True` to you DAG definition.
3. Because **sourcedir** is param and can be changed during execution, you need to use Dynamic Tasks (Airflow>=2.3.0) or creates a task the executes tasks.

Thats an example (without Dynamic Tasks):

```
with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 24),
        schedule_interval=None,
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        default_args={},
        params={
            "param2": "arya2@gmail.com",
            "sourcedir": ['/home/arya/'],
            "timenum": 0
        },
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    @task
    def make_list(lst):
        context = get_current_context()
        srcdir = []
        for number in range(0, len(lst)):
            srcdir.append(("abc" + lst[number] + "xyz"))
            taskinfo = EmptyOperator(task_id=f"taskinfo_{number}")
            taskinfo.execute(context)
        return srcdir

    make_list("{{ params.sourcedir }}")
```

Comment: Thanks ozs. I will try now.. But i missed to add len()  in the code, but in my original code len is already available

Comment: If we have multiple tasks outside of the definition  : how can we give dependency between two tasks..